# TypeError: Falsy value found in plugins - Vue Unit Testing with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, testing, jestjs

I have just started to write **test cases** for my already existing `Vue.js` project through ***Jest***.

The only test case that worked was Hello World in which it only checks for if the data is being rendered or not.

This is a custom spec which doesn't seem to be working.

I have created a **FancyHeading.spec.js** file

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import FancyHeading from '@/components/FancyHeading'

describe('FancyHeading', () => {
  test('if logged in is false, do not show logout button', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(FancyHeading)
    expect(wrapper.find('button').isVisible()).toBe(false)
  })

  test('if logged in, show logout button', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true)
    expect(1 + 1).toBe(2)
  })
})
```

For the below Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button class="btn" v-show="loggedIn">Logout</button>
  </div>
</template>

    <script>
export default {
  name: 'fancy-heading',
  data () {
    return {
      loggedIn: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The test case fails to run due to the following reason:

```
FAIL  tests/unit/FancyHeading.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Falsy value found in plugins

      at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:168:15
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Function.normalisePlugins (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:162:20)
      at OptionManager.mergeOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:239:36)
      at OptionManager.init (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:373:12)
      at File.initOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
      at new File (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
      at Pipeline.transform (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
      at compileBabel (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/compilers/babel-compiler.js:23:21)
      at processScript (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/process.js:30:10)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share your babel config?

Comment: I don't have a babel config, here's the .babelrc: ```{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", "dynamic-import-node"]
    }
  }
}
```